# pandas to_csv: suppress scientific notion for data frame with mixed types

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame with multiple columns whose types are either float64 or strings. I'm trying to use `to_csv` to write the data frame to an output file. However, it outputs big numbers with scientific notion. For example, if the number is 1344154454156.992676, it's saved in the file as 1.344154e+12.

How to suppress scientific notion for `to_csv` and keep the numbers as they are in the output file? I have tried to use `float_format` parameter in the `to_csv` function but it broke since there are also columns with strings in the data frame.

Here are some example codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['a','b','c'], 
                   'values': np.random.rand(3)*100000000000000})

df.to_csv('example.csv')

os.system("cat example.csv")
 ,names,values
0,a,9.41843213808e+13
1,b,2.23837359193e+13
2,c,9.91801198906e+13

# if i set up float_format:
df.to_csv('example.csv',  float_format='{:f}'.format)

ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

How can I get the data saved in the csv without scientific notion like below?

```
  names                values
0     a 94184321380806.796875
1     b 22383735919307.046875
2     c 99180119890642.859375
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The float_format argument should be a str, use this instead

```
df.to_csv('example.csv', float_format='%f')
```

Comment: I am glad it worked, :)
Can you please mark it as accepted answer, now that you see its working.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the options like this

```
pd.set_option('float_format', '{:f}'.format)
```

Answer (score 0):

> For python 3.xx (tested on 3.6.5 and 3.7):

[Options and Settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)

[For visualization of the dataframe pandas.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option)

```
import pandas as pd #import pandas package

# for visualisation fo the float data once we read the float data:

pd.set_option('display.html.table_schema', True) # to can see the dataframe/table as a html
pd.set_option('display.precision', 5) # setting up the precision point so can see the data how looks, here is 5
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['a','b','c'], 
               'values': np.random.rand(3)*100000000000000}) # generate random dataframe
```

## Output of the data:

```
df.dtypes # check datatype for columns

[output]:
names      object
values    float64
dtype: object
```

#### Dataframe:

```
df # output of the dataframe

[output]:
    names   values
0   a   6.56726e+13
1   b   1.63821e+13
2   c   7.63814e+13
```

#### And now write *to_csv* using the *float_format='%.13f'* parameter

```
df.to_csv('estc.csv',sep=',', float_format='%.13f') # write with precision .13
```

#### file output:

```
,names,values
0,a,65672589530749.0703125000000
1,b,16382088158236.9062500000000
2,c,76381375369817.2968750000000
```

#### And now write *to_csv* using the *float_format='%f'* parameter

```
df.to_csv('estc.csv',sep=',', float_format='%f') # this will remove the extra zeros after the '.'
```

#### file output:

```
,names,values
0,a,65672589530749.070312
1,b,16382088158236.906250
2,c,76381375369817.296875
```

[For more details check pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)